# Broken Dart Editor version 1.0.3_r30939 (DEV) Dart SDK version 1.0.3.0_r30939

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

My polymer-dart project use to run fine until I loaded Dart Editor version 1.0.3_r30939 (DEV)
Dart SDK version 1.0.3.0_r30939. Now I have this console output and failure to see my UI:

```
    Uncaught Error: Class '_LocalLibraryMirror' has no instance getter 'functions'.

    NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'functions'
    Receiver: Instance of '_LocalLibraryMirror@0x4863bc9'
    Arguments: []
    Stack Trace: 
    #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:45)
    #1      _loadLibrary (package:polymer/src/loader.dart:172:21)
    #2      _loadLibraries (package:polymer/src/loader.dart:89:19)
    #3      _initPolymerOptimized (package:polymer/src/loader.dart:54:17)
    #4      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:688)
    #5      _ZoneDelegate.run (dart:async/zone.dart:417)
    #6      _CustomizedZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:627)
    #7      initPolymer (package:polymer/src/loader.dart:37:33)
    #8      main (package:polymer/init.dart:23:22)....
```

Any help will be appreciated. I am using Windows 8 64 bit.

Thansk

Comment: did you run `pub upgrade`?

Comment: No, I did not. However, whenever I select the pubspec.yaml file and then click on Pub Upgrade I get a popup with the title "Unable to run pub" followed with Please select a pubspec.yaml before running pub. This occurs even though the file is selected.

Comment: Interesting ZOechi, clicking Pub Upgrade from the Tools menu does not work, but running it from pubspec.yaml context menu works. Everything is back to normal.